# get html element in ng-repeat angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to get to dom element that created in ng repeat i have this code and i dont understand why i cant get the element.

```
<div></div>
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="data in data"">
        {{data}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <script>
      var thirdListItem = $('ul').find('li').first().text();
        $('div').html(thirdListItem);
    </script>
```

here is plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/91S2esBo0uHzQHyEBuvj?p=preview

Comment: Why do you want to? It's usually a bad idea to mix jQuery and Angular like this.

Comment: when your script is executed the elements are not yet created.. because it is created as part of the digest cycle... you will have to use a custom directive to do it

Comment: This is an example. because lets say i need dynamically get the height or width of element before it render in the html, how can i get this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a nice idea to use AngularJS and jQuery together. Btw, try this quick&dirty solution:

```
  $(function(){
      var thirdListItem = $('ul').find('li').first().text();
      $('div').html(thirdListItem);
  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HDvZwPp1rFeoxVYb0qGd?p=preview

As somebody already said, the best practice would be to create a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: thats work fine. if you say its bad idea, what is the angular way?

Comment: as written in the answer, you should take a look to directives. I know it's attractive to mix up jQuery because you maybe know it already, but it's not clean code nor the best practice and it could lead to unexpected result and harder maintainance/debug

Comment: OK. but thats my question. i know how to write directives. I need a lead to accomplish something like what i wrote above.

Comment: From your questions, it's not really clear what you're asking. You can access elements after rendering using a directive that checks when the `ng-repeat` is over, and then operates on elements. Start from here: http://plnkr.co/edit/AQcfmUphHqBZ2phyB3X9?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

For your particular case try this solution:
It uses ng-init to pass the index value of the list item to a function which uses that index to return the DOM element using jQuery. Output is console.

http://plnkr.co/edit/XJnBzIyQoSJf9YKE0953?p=preview

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in data" ng-init="find($index +1)">
      {{data}}
    </li>
  </ul>

$scope.find = function(i){
       $ele= $('li:nth-child(' + i +')');
       console.log($ele);
  }
```

Comment: Guys im sorry for the misunderstood, but what im trying to accomplish is something like what i wrote in the third comment above.

Comment: Updated plunker to address your issue

Comment: OK I will to this now

Comment: It seems like this (size of your element) is really something that you shouldnt have to worry about given the proper CSS in the first place.

Comment: When directive is active this is happen after document.ready event?

Comment: Angular will not bootstrap a document until that document is '.ready'.  You can access your height and width using something like ...  console.log($ele.height() + ' ' + $ele.width());